# How to change the posts category with a button click

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am trying to create a button "Approved" to change the post category from it's current one to the "approved" category.  I don't mind if it reloads the page or not.  I would also like to redirect the page afterward to the next post in the original category.

I have found some questions on this already but am ultimately lost on how to get this all together and working.

```
<?php add_shortcode('approved_button', 'brist_approved_button_function');

function brist_approved_button_function() {
ob_start(); ?>

<form method="post" action="approved.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Approved" name="submit"> <!-- assign a name for the button -->
</form>


<?php

wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, intval( $_POST['approved'] ), 'category', false );
$output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;
}?>
```

Comment: Must it be a form? Why not just create an html button or a link and link to the approved page slug?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a form.  But the button does need to change the category.  Once the category is changed it removes it from a user's list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Though it was a head-scratcher for me.  If anyone else if having the same issue, note the code below. You have to create the select and then have the 'selected' option on the category you want the post to change to.  Then, in the CSS, hide the select input, only leaving the button.

```
<?php add_shortcode('approved_button', 'approved_button_function');?>


<?php function approved_button_function() { ob_start();?>
    <div class="approval">
        <form action="" id="update-post" method="post">
            <?php wp_dropdown_categories( "selected='categoryId'&exclude=21&class=approval-select&show_count=1&hierarchical=1&orderby=name&order=ASC&&hide_empty=0&show_option_all=Choose An Option" ); ?>
            <input class="approval-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Approve" />
        </form>
    </div>


<?php if ( array_key_exists('cat', $_POST )) {
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, intval( $_POST['cat'] ), 'category', false );
} ?>
```